# Why is ASP not finding anything in my database?

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

Initially my problem was that my posts were duplicating. I believe this was because I didn't link my tables in the SQL statement. Now that I have done that I am getting a "No Data Found" printed after my if info.eof statement.

I'm sure that there is information in the database as I have checked manually, however no success.

Here is my code:

```
<% option explicit %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
</head>

<body>
<!--#include file="header.asp"-->
<!--#include file="dbconn.asp"-->



<%


    dim sql, info

'                               0                 1      2        3         4                5              
 SQL = "select projectName, UserName, Category, Created, url, Projectstable.description "&_
        "from ProjectsTable, PictureTable, Usertable, CategoryTable "&_
        "where Projectstable.ID=PictureTable.projectNum AND "&_
        "categoryNum=CategoryTable.ID AND "&_
        "ProjectsTable.userNum=Usertable.ID AND "&_
        "UserTable.ID=PictureTable.userNum "&_
            "order by Created"

set info=conn.execute(SQL)

  if info.eof then
    response.write "<p>No Data Found</p>"
  else

    do 
      response.write "<h1>" & info(0) & "</h1> By: " & info(1) & " Posted in: " & info(2) & " Created on: " & info(3) & "<br>" &_
                     "<img src=""images/" &info(4)&""">" &_
                     "<p>" & info(5) & "</p>"

      info.movenext
    loop until info.eof
  end if 

  conn.close 

%>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to extract the query and run it directly against the database (in management studio if you are using SQL server). Does it show results?

Comment: @mortb You'll have to excuse me as I don't understand what you're suggesting. My Database is on Microsoft Access.

Comment: Could the problem be in dbconn.asp

Comment: @AndrewChappell It doesn't say that you are using access in your question. This is what I mean: Open your access database in access. Create a new query and switch to SQL view. Cut the SQL from your asp page code. Insert the sql into the access SQL view and run it. Does it show any results?

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten your query using ANSI 92 explicit join syntax rather than the ANSI 89 version you have used (which as the names suggest was replaced over 20 years ago with explicit joins):

```
SELECT  projectName, UserName, Category, Created, url, Projectstable.description
FROM    ProjectsTable
        INNER JOIN PictureTable
            ON Projectstable.ID = PictureTable.projectNum 
        INNER JOIN Usertable
            ON UserTable.ID = PictureTable.userNum
            AND ProjectsTable.userNum = Usertable.ID
        INNER JOIN CategoryTable
            ON categoryNum = CategoryTable.ID
ORDER BY Created;
```

Which highlighted to me that you are limiting your results to where the User in the picture table is the same as the user in the project table. Is this intentional?

Do you get the required results if you remove one of the criteria? So either

```
SELECT  projectName, UserName, Category, Created, url, Projectstable.description
FROM    ProjectsTable
        INNER JOIN PictureTable
            ON Projectstable.ID = PictureTable.projectNum 
        INNER JOIN Usertable
            ON UserTable.ID = PictureTable.userNum
            --AND ProjectsTable.userNum = Usertable.ID
        INNER JOIN CategoryTable
            ON categoryNum = CategoryTable.ID
ORDER BY Created;
```

Or

```
SELECT  projectName, UserName, Category, Created, url, Projectstable.description
FROM    ProjectsTable
        INNER JOIN PictureTable
            ON Projectstable.ID = PictureTable.projectNum 
        INNER JOIN Usertable
            ON ProjectsTable.userNum = Usertable.ID
            --AND UserTable.ID = PictureTable.userNum
        INNER JOIN CategoryTable
            ON categoryNum = CategoryTable.ID
ORDER BY Created;
```

For further reading on ANSI 89 vs ANSI 92 join syntax [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) has written [a great article about it](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) in his bad habits to kick series.

Comment: My lecturer is pretty old school so it doesn't surprise me. I'm still getting the same issue when I leave either out. 
I think I want the user to be the same but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in fact errors in the database itself. More pointedly, it was incorrect linking between tables. The SQL statement might be outdated but it wasn't causing the errors.